# UIPageViewController funcs not being called when it's embedded in a Container on a different UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I have created a Main.storyboard ViewController and associated custom class that derives from `UIPageView` and implements `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` and `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` protocols.

It works fine when setting it up as it's own ViewController but when I embedded it in the actual view I want the ability to flip between views in (using a Container), it doesn't respond to swipe gestures or invoke the protocols like it does in on it's own.

I've been keeping the implementation of the protocols in this separate ViewController class and while the viewDidLoad method is invoked the protocols aren't.  I am setting `delegate=self` and `dataSource=self`.  Is it customary to keep this as a separate ViewController or should I be implementing these protocols on the parent ViewController that includes the container?

Any other suggestions of what could be going wrong?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Mike

Comment: You do not need a separate view controller for protocols. It is more customary to extend the view controller that the objects are in. See Apple’s pages on [extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) and [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the guidance.  I had a hunch the problem was related to which ViewController was implementing the protocols.  It took me a few minutes to figure out how to do it w/o the help of a another ViewController since the embedded segue was creating the object.

Simple answer was to programmatically create the PageViewController in the ViewController I was working in and have that class be the delegate, etc.  Simple as the line of code:

`self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)`

Now the events are firing and all of the code is in one place.